# How to remove empty lines from cells in Excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Here's what I'm trying to achieve through all the cells in the worksheet containing a string, with limited success so far:

|    EXAMPLE          |
 cell1_empty_line
 cell1_text1
 cell1_empty_line
+---------------------+
 cell2_text1
 cell2_emptyline
 cell2_text2
+---------------------+
 cell3_emptyline
 cell3_emptyline
 cell3_text1
+---------------------+

|    EXPECTED RESULT  |
 cell1_text1
+---------------------+
 cell2_text1
 cell2_text2
+---------------------+
 cell3_text1
+---------------------+

Any suggestion for such a macro?

Many thanks.

Comment: Data Tab: filter.  Unselect all.  Select blank highlight blank rows and press delete button.  remove filter.

Answer (score 3):

Use this macro to remove any empty lines inside all cells:

```
Sub TrimEmptyLines()
    Dim cel As Range, s As String, len1 As Long, len2 As Long
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsError(cel.Value2) Then
            If InStr(1, cel.text, vbLf) > 0 Then
                s = Trim(cel.Value2)
                Do ' remove duplicate vbLf
                    len1 = Len(s)
                    s = Replace$(s, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
                    len2 = Len(s)
                Loop Until len2 = len1

                ' remove vblf at beginning or at end
                If Left$(s, 1) = vbLf Then s = Right$(s, Len(s) - 1)
                If Right$(s, 1) = vbLf Then s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)

                cel.value = Trim$(s)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with just one cell and its blank lines within then one of these should work:

`Cells.Replace what:=Chr(13), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart`

`Cells.Replace what:=Chr(10), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart`

Answer (score 1):

This is general enough to handle any column of cells with any # of line feeds in each cell. It assumes all your values are in column "A" starting at row 1 of the active sheet:

```
Public Function RemoveDoubleLfs(str As String) As String
  If InStr(str, vbLf & vbLf) > 0 Then
     str = RemoveDoubleLfs(Replace(str, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf))
  End If
  RemoveDoubleLfs = str
End Function


Sub RemoveEmptyLines()
  Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '

  Dim val As String
  For i = 1 To lastRow:
    val = Cells(i, "A").Value

    If InStr(1, val, vbLf) > 0 Then
      val = RemoveDoubleLfs(val)

      If Left(val, 1) = vbLf Then val = Right(val, Len(val) - 1)
      If Right(val, 1) = vbLf Then val = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
      Cells(i, "A").Value = val
    End If
  Next

  ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

The recursive replace function gets rid of double line feeds in the text of the cell.  Once that's done there will be at most one VbLf at the beginning and end of the string.  The last two if statements look for and remove the latter.

The autofit at the end is optional and is there purely to prettify the result; it just compacts the cells to their minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing this solution please set the values of the two variables at the top.

```
FirstDataColumn = 1
FirstDataRow = 2
```

This setting leaves starts with the first column but leaves out the first row which might contain column captions.

> Sub RemoveBlanks()
>
> ```
> Dim FirstDataColumn As Long, FirstDataRow As Long
> Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
> Dim Tmp As Variant, Arr As Variant
> Dim Counter As Integer
> Dim C As Long, R As Long
>
> FirstDataColumn = 1
> FirstDataRow = 2
>
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> With ActiveSheet
>     With .UsedRange
>         LastColumn = .Columns.Count
>         LastRow = .Rows.Count
>     End With
>     For C = FirstDataColumn To LastColumn
>         ReDim Arr(LastRow, 0)
>         Counter = 0
>         For R = FirstDataRow To LastRow
>             Tmp = Trim(.Cells(R, C).Value)
>             If Len(Tmp) Then
>                 Arr(Counter, 0) = Tmp
>                 Counter = Counter + 1
>             End If
>         Next R
>         .Cells(FirstDataRow, C).Resize(LastRow, 1).Value = Arr
>     Next C
> End With
> Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> ```
>
> End Sub